# Shimano 105 + Shimano Tiagra?

Tags: shimano, crankset, groupsets, road

I am looking to buy a new high end performance road bike soon along with a power meter. I'm looking at possibly a Shimano 105 or Tiagra groupset. However, stages doesn't make a power meter for Tiagra crank arms. Is it possible to ride with a Tiagra right drive side crank and a Shimano 105 left side crank? I know its a silly question and it probably wont work but all in the name of saving money!

Comment: If you want a new *high end* performance road bike then just pay the couple hundred dollar extra for 105.  It is $500 meter.   If you need to save money then skip the meter.

Comment: Did it work out for you? They have 4 mm of difference in Q factor. I wonder if that would reduce the contact surface where the crank meets the spindle?

Answer (score 5):

Latest 105 and Tiagra iterations at this moment are 4700 and 5800. Both have same crankset design, so I don't see why left crankarm wouldn't be compatible. I'd figure you would be more concerned about color mismatch. There's also a slight weight difference, but I doubt most riders would notice it.

Comment: As long as they're both similar colours (ie both silver or both black) then design differences won't be noticed.  Its not like someone can see both sides at the same time to compare cranks.

Comment: There's going to be as weight mismatch no matter what you do between the left and right side cranks because one side is just the crank arm while the other side contains the entire chainset.